# What to do after discovering possible asbestos tiles under carpet?

Tags: flooring

I want to replace the carpet in a house I moved into recently (the carpet is in bad shape). After beginning to rip it up to see what was beneath it / subfloor, I found what looks like tiles. Before proceeding I checked the original blueprints for the house and found that the rooms I'd like to replace carpet in originally had VAT flooring. Had a couple questions before I proceed.

1. I've never seen tiles like this before with little grooves in them. Are they indeed tiles? I am likely just uninformed on this but I wanted to confirm that these are indeed tiles and not some subfloor or underlayment.
2. If they are VAT tiles, should I even consider removing them myself? There are varying opinions on this that range from stopping everything and getting an abatement team involved, all the way to handling this myself in a safe manner (wetting, slowly prying up, removing safely, covering vents). Are there other more options I should be considering and/or tossing out?

For context under the rubber baseboard trim I can see that the tile is relatively thin on top of whatever layer is beneath.

[image]  [image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is some info about VAT flooring.  Harvard says it poses no risk to public health.  ( If not disturbed)

[VAT Flooring](https://www.ehs.harvard.edu/sites/default/files/vinyl_asbestos_tile_fact_sheet.pdf)

I think if you leave it alone you can re-carpet over it.

Comment: Or floating floor, if you don't want carpet.

Comment: The paper at that link addresses replacing carpet: "Jobs requiring removal of carpet from a VAT covered floor should be reviewed by EH&S [Environmental Health and Safety]. If tiles remain attached to carpet or are broken during the work, they must be removed by a licensed asbestos contractor." I'd think the last sentence is the key: safe as long as nothing breaks.